# azure ADF Pipeline query

Tags: azure

How to write where clause in select query.

The below statement gives error for where clause, whats the syntax, I need to bring limited data from source table, please help

```
 "sqlReaderQuery": "$$Text.Format('Select OwningBusinessUnitName],[OwningTeam],[OwningTeamName],[StatusCodeName],[StateCodeName],[PriorityCode],[PriorityCodeName],[ActivityUrlLink],[Description] FROM Activities WHERE [CreatedOn] >= '216-02-01')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at [the documentation and examples here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-sql-connector/#azure-sql-dataset-type-properties), you need to escape the single quotes:

```
"SqlReaderQuery": "$$Text.Format('SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE StartDateTime = \\'{0:yyyyMMdd-HH}\\'', WindowStart)"
```

Note, it is double back-slash! (may be omitted here due to formatting)
After all, you are editing a JSON where single quotes do have quite a meaning:

Comment: I already saw the documentation and tried without single quote didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had a complex sql query that had numerous single quotes.  Escaping them with:

```
\\'
```

didn't work.  However, escaping them with \' did work.  Escaping using \' is not correct from a JSON perspective, but that is what worked.